# Xamarin and no mac, building with macincloud

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

As Xamarin needs a mac to serve as a build host I'm renting a mac from macincloud. However, the trial which gave me the business edition worked well with the build host - the starter edition does not. I'm not granted access to the build host anymore. I'd be happy to buy an indie game license, but it seems that this doesn't give me access to the build host either. (Or does it? I haven't tried yet).

It's stated on the xamarin page that the starter edt. Will give me the option of building apps, but how do I do this when using Visual Studio on my PC? VS needs to be paired with a build host on a mac for the MainStoryBoard to work, so it appears I do need the build host, if I'm programming from a pc. Summing this up; what do I need to do the get the connection between Xamarin (on the mac) and VS (2010 / 12 / 13) on my PC to work? I'm using professional VS edition.

Comment: *It's stated on the xamarin page that the starter edt. will give me the option of building apps, but how do I do this when using Visual Studio on my PC?* Either pay for the edition that allows you to use Visual Studio or use Xamarin Studio on your Mac. There's one big fat heading that says *Develop with Xamarin Studio* on the start page http://xamarin.com/starter

Comment: You are correct at that, however when attempting to use xamarin studio it says "ios projects are not supported in xamarin studio on windows". So I was under the impression that there must be something off here. 

Are you sure, that it's not possible to use VS to develop apps on a PC, then connecting to a Mac and build them, without the business edition? (Also, reminding you that using words like "big fat heading" could scare less experienced programmers away from this forum...)

Comment: Dude.. you're all about sunshine, rainbows, unicorns and happy thougts aren't you? My bad for using the word "forum", English is not my native language. I'm sure you understood what I meant anyhow?

Comment: You must have a Business Edition license to use Visual Studio with a Mac Build Host.