# Using an iPad as the networked Mac for Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

This guide explains how to use Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio and a network available Mac as the host for Apple's complier:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/

**It is possible to use an iPad as the networked Apple compliler?**

Comment: Why is my question marked down while this question is given an up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957109/xamarin-and-no-mac-building-with-macincloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot run XCode on an iOS device, therefore it cannot be used as a Xamarin build host. If you do not have a Mac to act as a build host, you can get one in the cloud from something like [this](http://www.macincloud.com/) or any similar service